# Does apportable support for sqllite at all?

Tags: apportable

I tried to do "apportable build" on my project that makes reference to sqllite.  I get linking error.  What should I do?

### Here's the error log

> ```
> Packaging assets/exchangeothergamebtn_d.png
> Packaging assets/exchangeothergameview.xib
> Packaging assets/exchmenu.png
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:33: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_prepare_v2'
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:34: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_bind_int'
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:35: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_bind_int'
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:36: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_bind_int'
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:37: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_bind_int'
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:48: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_step'
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:49: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_finalize'
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:58: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_prepare_v2'
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:59: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_step'
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:61: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_column_int'
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:62: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_column_int'
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:63: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_column_int'
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:64: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_column_int'
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:103: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_exec'
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:105: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_exec'
> /android/bacc/UserInfo.m:109: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_finalize'
> Packaging assets/exchptbg.png
> Packaging assets/ar.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
> /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCFeaturedApp/TJCFeaturedAppDBManager.m:66:
> ```
>
> error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_open'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCFeaturedApp/TJCFeaturedAppDBManager.m:70:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_prepare_v2'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCFeaturedApp/TJCFeaturedAppDBManager.m:76:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_bind_text'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCFeaturedApp/TJCFeaturedAppDBManager.m:80:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_step'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCFeaturedApp/TJCFeaturedAppDBManager.m:85:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_finalize'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCFeaturedApp/TJCFeaturedAppDBManager.m:104:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_close'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCFeaturedApp/TJCFeaturedAppDBManager.m:120:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_open'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCFeaturedApp/TJCFeaturedAppDBManager.m:129:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_prepare_v2'
>       Packaging assets/English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCFeaturedApp/TJCFeaturedAppDBManager.m:135:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_step'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCFeaturedApp/TJCFeaturedAppDBManager.m:140:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_finalize'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCFeaturedApp/TJCFeaturedAppDBManager.m:159:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_close'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCFeaturedApp/TJCFeaturedAppDBManager.m:181:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_open'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCFeaturedApp/TJCFeaturedAppDBManager.m:184:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_get_table'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCFeaturedApp/TJCFeaturedAppDBManager.m:197:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_free_table'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCFeaturedApp/TJCFeaturedAppDBManager.m:210:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_close'
>       Packaging assets/zh_CN.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/zh_TW.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCVirtualGoods/TJCVG_LocalDatabase/TJCSqliteController.m:61:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_open'
>       Packaging assets/vi.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCVirtualGoods/TJCVG_LocalDatabase/TJCSqliteController.m:135:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_close'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCVirtualGoods/TJCVG_LocalDatabase/TJCSqliteController.m:208:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_column_text'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCVirtualGoods/TJCVG_LocalDatabase/TJCSqliteController.m:291:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_bind_text'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCVirtualGoods/TJCVG_LocalDatabase/TJCSqliteController.m:292:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_bind_text'
>       /android/bacc/baccaratgame/TapjoyConnect/Components/TJCVirtualGoods/TJCVG_LocalDatabase/TJCSqliteController.m:294:
>   error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_bind_text'
>       Packaging assets/tr.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/tr-TR.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/th.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Build/android-armeabi-debug/jsk.vipbaccarat/Baccarat/libBaccarat.a(scorecard.m.o):/android/bacc/baccaratgame/baccrsc/scorecard.m:function
>   L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_71: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_CLASS_$_DMAdView'
>       Packaging assets/sv.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/es.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/ru.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/pt.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/nn.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/nb.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/ms.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/ko.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/ja.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/it.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/id.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/fr.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/fi.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/el.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/nl.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/de.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/da.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
>       Packaging assets/LICENSE.txt
>       Packaging assets/README.markdown
>       Packaging assets/NetErrorView.xib
>       Packaging assets/21dian.sql
>       Packaging assets/adback.png
>       Packaging assets/AdWindow.xib
>       Packaging assets/57A.png
>       Packaging assets/cafeicon.png
>       Packaging assets/gangwar57.png
>       Packaging assets/glory.png
>       Packaging assets/glorycn.png
>       Packaging assets/heishehui.png
>       Packaging assets/ifarm.png
>       Packaging assets/keaicanting.png
>       Packaging assets/newgame.png
>       Packaging assets/ranchcn.png
>       Packaging assets/sjdz.png
>       scons: *** [Build/android-armeabi-debug/Baccarat/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so]
>   Error 1
>       scons: building terminated because of errors.
>       Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'" in > ignored

Answer (score 1):

Add "sqlite" to the "deps" section of "add_params" in configuration.json

Comment: This answer contradicts the bug tracker, here: http://code.google.com/p/apportable/issues/detail?id=8 Which is correct?

Comment: sqlite is built into the SDK. I just updated the bug tracker. Provide more details if it's not working for you